# using a bash variable inside expect

Tags: bash, expect

I have a file called profiles.txt and each line contains a number i.e

11
24
35
46

Using the below script I read the file and store each line as a variable the issue i'm having is that i'm unable to use this variable in the expect part. Is there a way to do it all in expect?

`````
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf -v "profile$((i++))" '%s' "$line"
done < profiles.txt

/usr/bin/expect <(cat << EOF

spawn telnet 0.0.0.0
send -- "$profile1\r"
send -- "exit\r"
EOF
)````
`````

Comment: Embedding Expect code in shell scripts is kind of tricky and error-prone. You can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Answer (score 0):

Move the `expect` inside the `while`:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    /usr/bin/expect <(cat << EOF
        spawn telnet 0.0.0.0
        send -- "$line\r"
        send -- "exit\r"
EOF
)
done < /tmp/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with here-strings instead:

```
xyz="woot" # a bash variable

expect <<<'
  # a tcl variable
  set abc "zoot"

  puts "This is the bash var: '$xyz'"
  puts "This is the tcl var: $abc"
  puts "This is how you put a single quote: '\''"
'
```

Produces:

```
This is the bash var: woot
This is the tcl var: zoot
This is how you put a single quote: '
```

Everything in the single-quotes is passed to expect verbatim. But the shell variable is written as '$xyz', it's actually outside the single quotes and gets expanded as part of the string.

Bash's embedded single-quote escapes are clumsy, fortunately tcl supports use of { } for literal strings so you can usually avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can "*do it all in expect*" with no `bash` required.  Expect is built on top of Tcl so you have access to all the Tcl commands - https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/contents.html .  Here is one way:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set file [open profiles.txt]
while {[gets $file profile] >= 0} {

    spawn telnet 0.0.0.0
    # At this point you should probably do 'expect someprompt'
    # to make sure that telnet has connected before you start sending
    send -- "$profile\r"
    send -- "exit\r"
    
}
close $file
```